# trying to understand one jquery example

Tags: jquery

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
         <div id="log"></div>
         <script>
            $("a").click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $('<div/>')
                  .append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
                  .appendTo('#log');
            });
         </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Above code is taken from: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Question:

1. `function(event)`, I know here event means:click, but how did the click object pass the value to this parameter:event?
2. ```
   $('<div/>')
   .append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
   .appendTo('#log');
   ```

I know `append()` and `appendTo()`, but still had a hard time to understand this line,  `$('<div/>')` means to create a `<div/>`? Usually I only see this style:   `$('div').append()`, can anyone explain this line to me? thanks.

Comment: for your first question read the explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#DOM_Event_interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object to the `event` parameter is automatically passed by jQuery when the event is trigger.

`$('<div/>')` will create a new `<div></div>` element.

`.append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')` will add "default click prevented" to the newly created div, so it will become something like `<div>default click prevented</div>`

`.appendTo('#log');` will append the entire above div to `#log` element i.e if you consider your `#log` elements as `<div id="log"></div>`, it will then become

```
<div id="log">

    <div>default click prevented</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Understood, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').append('...')
```

Here 'div' selector will search for all DIVs already in DOM and append content to them.

```
$('<div/>').append('...')
```

Here, we create new element DIV wrapped in jquery object and append content to it.
This is the same as:  `$('<div>').append('...')` or  `$('<div></div>').append('...')`  just the syntax change.

You have still to add to the DOM the new created element. Usually then, you can use `.appendTo(elementInDOM)` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shortcut for creating a div-element, which contains the text of your append() statement. This DIV will be appended to your #log element.
Another example for your understanding:

```
$('<div />').html('This is a simple text-string').appendTo('body');
```

The long form would/could be:

```
$('<div>After this point comes a new string:<br /></div>').html('This is a simple text-string').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

`event` not only means to click, it can be any event like keyup,keydown,mouseover,mouseout,

Also if to want to get the value from the clicked event then use `$(this)`

List of all [Events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

**Second**

```
$('div').append('text');
```

will append text`to the`selecter`$('div')` and
here in your question you are creating a div then appends some text in it which shows the line

```
$('<div/>').append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
```

which is then `appended` to `#log`